# How to define exp for Church Numerals in coq?

Tags: coq, logical-foundations

I am currently learning coq thanks to the [Software Fondation's ebook](https://softwarefoundations.cis.upenn.edu/current/lf-current/Poly.html).
I successfully wrote the addition as follow:

```
Definition cnat := forall X : Type, (X -> X) -> X -> X.
Definition plus (n m : cnat) : cnat :=
  fun (X : Type) (f : X -> X) (x : X) => n X f (m X f x).
```

But I'm stuck with exp because of the following error:

```
Definition exp (n m : cnat) : cnat :=
  m cnat (mult n) n.
(*
In environment
n : cnat
m : cnat
The term "cnat" has type "Type@{cnat.u0+1}"
while it is expected to have type "Type@{cnat.u0}"
(universe inconsistency). 
*)
```

Since they wrote:

> If you hit a "Universe inconsistency" error, try iterating over a different type. Iterating over cnat itself is usually problematic.
> I tried using the definition of cnat:

```
Definition exp (n m : cnat) : cnat :=
  m (forall X : Type, (X -> X) -> X) (mult n) n.
```

But then I have:

```
In environment
n : cnat
m : cnat
The term "mult n" has type "cnat -> cnat"
while it is expected to have type
 "(forall X : Type, (X -> X) -> X) -> forall X : Type, (X -> X) -> X"
(universe inconsistency).
```

I do not ask for a solution, but I'd really like to understand these errors.
Thanks for your lights !

Comment: A first step towards understanding these errors is to ask Coq to print more information so that we can actually see the culprit with `Set Printing Universes.`.
These are not printed by default to keep output readable. 

Then to understand the error itself, note that in order to define `cnat` you are quantifying over all types in some universe `Type@{i}`. In order to keep the calculus consistent Coq has to put `cnat` in a greater universe `Type@{j}` for `i < j` (see Girard's paradox), so you cannot instantiate `cnat` with itself (what's called impredicativity).

Answer (score 8):

Just post the solution for others who got stuck on this problem.

```
Definition exp (n m : cnat) : cnat := 
  fun X => (m (X->X)) (n X).
```

The key is to understand `m (X->X)`. The figure below might be helpful.

An example of 2 ^ 2

[image: An example of 2 ^ 2]

Comment: I would never have gotten this one, thanks